# http-Get request with empty response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to process the response of a http-request with JavaScript. You can find a simple example here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
  <title>JavaScript Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function serviceCall() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:8181/geoserver/wfs?Service=WFS&Request=GetFeature&Version=1.0.0&typename=topp:tasmania_water_bodies&SRS=EPSG:4326',
//        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows?Service=WFS&Request=GetFeature&Version=1.0.0&typename=topp:tasmania_water_bodies&SRS=EPSG:4326',
        complete: function(xml, status){
          alert(xml.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <center><button onclick="serviceCall()">Start...</button></center>
</body>
</html>
```

The request works directly in a browser. Via Ajax and JavaScript the response is empty. Firebug reports a xml parsing error at line 1, column 1. I've tried to send the request to localhost and to a remote server but the response is always empty. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: What do you expect for response content?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: why are you handling complete and not the success event of ajax?

Comment: If not just some invalid XML, it might be a cross-domain-ajax issue

Comment: Agree with @ryadavilli -- probably your request is failing (likely due to the same origin policy) and your jqXHR object doesn't have any `responseText`. You don't see that, however, since you don't have a `success` or `error` handler (and the `complete` handler fires regardless of success or failure).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `success` instead of `complete`? Since `complete` is fired always, even if it failed, and `success` only if it was successfull. Than you don't need the `xml, status`.

Example (not working since CORS):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost:8181/geoserver/wfs?Service=WFS&Request=GetFeature&Version=1.0.0&typename=topp:tasmania_water_bodies&SRS=EPSG:4326',
    success: function(response){
      alert(response);
    }
  });
```

Also if you wan't to access a different domain. You can use JSONP if you own the other domain. Otherwise it is not possible.

Try to add the following part to the URL: `&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:processJSON`

**Working None jQuery example** (LIVE EXAMPLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/QWgJa/)

```
function loadJSON(url)
{
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
    var newScript = document.createElement("script");
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = url;
    headID.appendChild(newScript);  
}
function processJSON(jsonData)
{
    alert(jsonData); 
}

loadJSON("http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows?Service=WFS&Request=GetFeature&Version=1.0.0&typename=topp:tasmania_water_bodies&SRS=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&format_options=callback:processJSON");
```

Information URLs

- [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
- [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Generally correct; however, [cross-origin resource sharing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (CORS) is a way for the server to allow the browser to complete cross-domain Ajax requests. It's a much cleaner solution than JSONP (although JSONP is supported in older browsers).

Comment: Still JSONP is the only solution for CORS.

Comment: I'm afraid don't understand your comment. [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) are two completely separate approaches to avoid the restrictions of the same-origin policy. CORS uses special server headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` which inform the browser to ignore the same-origin policy if the request comes from a specific origin. As I said, CORS  excludes some older browsers, since it requires a CORS-aware browser. Thus, JSON has the widest support, but it is not the only solution.

Comment: Updated my post, it is possible to retreive the data through JSONP. I've posted an example of the URL in my post.